# Error: Full authentication is required to access this resource when using @PreAuthorize

Tags: java, authentication, jwt, postman

I am trying to implement a authentication using Spring Boot, JWT with Roles

**I have the error:**

> full authentication is required to access this resource

when send **POST** request
to "http://localhost:8080/api/profile/edit_user_detail" (with authoziration header)

**Below is my **Controller****

```
@Controller
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*",maxAge = 3600)
@RequestMapping("/api/profile")
public class UserAPI {

    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository;
    @Autowired
    private RoleRepository roleRepository;
    @Autowired
    QARepository qaRepository;
    @Autowired
    DiscussRepository discussRepository;
    @Autowired
    AnnouncementRepository announcementRepository;

    @PostMapping(value = {"/edit_user_detail"})
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_USER')")
    public ResponseEntity<?> editInfo(@RequestBody Map map) throws ParseException {
        String username = map.get("username").toString();
        String display_name = map.get("display_name").toString();

        User user = userRepository.findByUserName(username).get(0);
        user.setuDigitalName(display_name);
       
        userRepository.save(user);

        return ResponseEntity.ok("Updated");
    }
```

**But when i remove the line**

> @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_USER')")

then i can success POST the request and edited successfully the user (I have checked in database)

**Also this is my EntryPoint (to catch Exception)**

```
@Component
public class AuthEntryPointJwt implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AuthEntryPointJwt.class);
    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse, AuthenticationException e) throws IOException, ServletException {
        log.error("Authorized error: " + e.getMessage());
        httpServletResponse.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED,"Error: Unauthorized");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**And this is my Configuration file**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class ConfigAuthenticate extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsServices userDetailsServices;

    @Autowired
    private AuthEntryPointJwt unauthorizeHandler;

    @Bean
    public AuthTokenFilter authenticationJwtTokenFilter(){
        return new AuthTokenFilter();
    }
    @Bean
    @Override public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsServices).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().and().csrf().disable().exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizeHandler)
                .and().sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and().authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();

        http.addFilterBefore(authenticationJwtTokenFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }

}
```

I think there are a problem with configuration in **WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter** , i have try to

- Change `@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_USER')")` to `@PreAuthorize("hasRole('USER')")`
- Check the JWT Token in header, also the ROLE in database

but it's still not work, anybody have solution

Answer (score 1):

Try removing `.antMatchers("/**").permitAll()`, and add these lines to your:

application.yml

```yaml
logging:
  level:
    org.springframework.security: TRACE
```

or application.properties

```
logging.level.org.springframework.security=TRACE
```

And you could see the information about your user like this:

```
AnonymousAuthenticationToken [Principal=anonymousUser, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=null], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_ANONYMOUS]]
```

You can rely on `Granted Authorities` in order to determine user's roles

---

Because you're setting `.antMatchers("/**").permitAll()` before `.anyRequest().authenticated()`, I'm not so sure whether you validated the user successfully or not. If not, then the `AnonymousAuthenticationFilter` will create an anonymous user for you. And in case you don't add `@PreAuthorize("hasRole('USER')")`,
the `FilterSecurityInterceptor`, bases on `.antMatchers("/**").permitAll()`, will allow the request gets through it and accesses the controller.

Comment: Thank you for your response, i have checked and that's true, when i change to @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ANONYMOUS')") then it works but i this way anyone (include not login one) can user this api. I want to check check ROLE_USER which i have on login response here, any idea
{
    "token": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.e...",
    "type": "Bearer",
    "id": 1,
    "username": "tin",
    "email": "tin@gmail.com",
    "roles": [
        "ROLE_USER"
    ]
}

Comment: @Đoàn It depends on your filter implementation, I saw you set `http.addFilterBefore(authenticationJwtTokenFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);`. So the responsibility here belongs to your `AuthTokenFilter`, I have no idea but one thing I want to bring up is **don't forget to set the SecurityContext** after you successfully validate your user or check that you had it by implementing some abstract filter. E.g: 
```
Authentication auth = ...;
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(auth);
```

Comment: Very true, i forgot to set SecurityContext: SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(...);. The issue resolved, many thanks